# Android emulator no keyboard

Tags: android, adt, android-virtual-device

I downloaded the ADT Bundle for linux, but it doesn't show the keyboard on the rightside and also doesn't recognize my keyboard. If I check in the option in AVD "Hardware keyboard present", then that provide the same result. In the hardware-properties.ini file I found this:

```
# Keyboard support (qwerty/azerty)
name        = hw.keyboard
type        = boolean
default     = no
abstract    = Keyboard support
description = Whether the device has a QWERTY keyboard.
```

If I change the "default" to yes, then also nothing happen. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your emulator `.ini` file (it should be somewhere in `~/.android/avd/`) and add line like:

```
hw.keyboard=yes
```